# Как определить формальную тактовую частоту ЦП с помощью WinAPI?

Tags: winapi, cpu

Нужно определить тактовую частоту ЦП, которая написана на коробке, с помощью функций WinAPI (т.е. вариант с извлечением из реестра не подходит).

Любые попытки поиска приводят к дискуссиям о том, как найти фактическую частоту в данный момент времени. Мне посоветовали использовать "CallNtPowerInformation" либо "QueryPerformanceFrequency", но возник ряд проблем. Начну с "QueryPerformanceFrequency": при всём желании я так и не понял, что она возвращает. Объясняю: частота моего ЦП ~1.1 ГГц, а функция возвращает значение "100 000 000". В чём измеряется это значение? В Гц? Тогда это 100 МГц, что не соответствует действительности.

"CallNtPowerInformation". Тут проблема посложнее, и, честно говоря, я понятия не имею, как её решить. Данная функция в заголовке "powerbase.h" у меня закомментирована директивой "#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP | WINAPI_PARTITION_SYSTEM)", однако вызов функции всё-таки осуществляется (сборка и выполнение проходят успешно). Проблема в том, что она отрабатывает с ошибкой, возвращая отрицательное число в качестве кода ошибки, что довольно странно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CallNtPowerInformation` всего-навсего обертка над `NtPowerInformation`, экспортируемой из `ntdll.dll`. Прототип функции выглядит как:

```
NTSYSCALLAPI
NTSTATUS
NTAPI
NtPowerInformation(
  POWER_INFORMATION_LEVEL InformationLevel,
  PVOID                   InputBuffer,
  ULONG                   InputBufferLength,
  PVOID                   OutputBuffer,
  ULONG                   OutputBufferLength
);
```

В вашем случае `POWER_INFORMATION_LEVEL` равен 11 (`ProcessorInformation`), описываемого структурой

```
typedef struct _PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION {
    ULONG Number;
    ULONG MaxMhz;
    ULONG CurrentMhz;
    ULONG MhzLimit;
    ULONG MaxIdleState;
    ULONG CurrentIdleState;
} PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION, *PPROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION;
```

Для начала вам следует получить количество количество процессоров в системе, а вот как вы это будете делать - через `GetSystemInfo` или `NtQuerySystemInformation`, - дело сугубо личное. Ну, а далее можно поступить примерно так:

```
typedef std::vector<PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION> vppi;

vppi ppi;
NTSTATUS nts;

/* получили количество процессоров  равное NumOfCpu, см. комментарий выше */
ppi.resize(NumOfCpu);

nts = NtPowerInformation(ProcessorInformation, nullptr, 0, &ppi[0], sizeof(PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION) * ppi.size());

if (!NT_SUCCESS(nts)) {
  /* обработка NTSTATUS */
  return 1;
}

for (vppi::iterator i = ppi.begin(); i != ppi.end(); ++i) {
   std::cout << L"Max MHz: " << i->MaxMhz << std::endl;
}
```

Можно, в принципе, не заморачиваться количеством процессоров, а просто передать `NtPowerInformation` адрес `PROCESSOR_POWER_INFORMATION`, но это несколько варварский способ.<